# Using CallByName to set Item(x) property

Tags: vb.net

As a bit of background, I have a [.net <-> COM object bridge](https://github.com/EionRobb/PHP-DotNet-Bridge/blob/master/Universal_CCW_source.vb) that uses VB.net as a middleman, with a lot of reflection to get the job done.

I've run into a hurdle where I'm needing to use CallByName() to set a pretty standard property which is defined as

```
    Public Default Property Item ( 
        index As Integer
    ) As String
        Get
        Set
```

which would normally be called as `.Object(1) = "new value"`, however the bridge code at the moment tries to get .Object(1) as an object then call Set on it using CallByName() (which obviously doesn't work).

With other collections I am happily able to use CallByName() to make method calls `.Clear()` and `.Add("new value")` but this property doesn't have these methods and besides, I'd like to solve it for a more generic approach so that code from the other side of the bridge can call the `.Object` directly.

Is someone able to suggest a way to Set an array-type property directly using CallByName(), or perhaps suggest an alternative reflection function that can be called to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default property can be used as a normal property, using its name.  So, given a class:

```
Class Foo
    Default Public Property Item(index As Integer) As String
        Get
            '...
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            '...
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

These three property assignments all have the same effect:

```
    Dim Bar As New Foo
    Bar(1) = "x"
    Bar.Item(1) = "x"
    CallByName(Bar, "Item", CallType.Set, 1, "x")
```

For array-type properties, the parameter(s) are passed to CallByName before the value when setting.

Answer (score 2):

You did not show how you were using `CallByName` on that property, which leaves us to guess what is wrong.  The syntax of `.Object(1) = "new value"` is also a little confusing: does the leading dot means that `Object` itself is some sort of collection on some other Type?

The basic answer lies in looking at the declaration, not how it is used normally.  The fact that you can omit "Item" normally because it is the Default, does not apply here:

```
'foo(1) ==> foo.Item(1) = "Ziggy" ==> 
CallByName(foo, "Item", CallType.Set, 1, "Ziggy")
```

The `procName` argument would be the property name, `Item` in this case.  `CallType.Set` means you want the prop setter (Let or Set seem to both work).  The first argument would be the index of the item to set/get, the last would be the data to pass.

If `.Object` is supposed to mean you are trying to reference a collection property, then the answer is about the same:

```
'foo.bars(1) ==> foo.Bars.Item(1) = "Zoey" ==> 
CallByName(foo.Bars, "Item", CallType.Set, 1, "Zoey")
```